# Reload an Activity when a certain object is clicked? [Kotlin, Android]

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, android-recyclerview

#### Information

I'm using a RecyclerView to display data from a sqlite database.
Some objects represent folders/layers. If a User clicks on a folder/layer there is new data that should be displayed. The new data needs to be retrieved from the database.

#### Assumptions

To display the new data the RecyclerViewAdapter (CustomAdapter in the code snippet) needs to be called again. This leads to my Question.

#### Question

How do I manage to refresh an Activity if a certain object is klicked?

#### MainActivity.kt

```
package com.example.todo

import android.content.Context
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import android.widget.*
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val spinner: Spinner = findViewById(R.id.create_new)
        setAdapter(spinner)

        //RecyclerView
        createRecyclerView(this)

    }

    private fun setAdapter(spinner: Spinner) {
        ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this,
                R.array.create_new,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item
        ).also { adapter ->
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
            spinner.adapter = adapter
            spinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
                override fun onItemSelected(
                        parent: AdapterView<*>?,
                        view: View,
                        position: Int,
                        id: Long
                ) {
                    val selected = parent?.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()
                    if (selected.equals("Ebene")) {
                        Snackbar.make(view, "spinner: ebene", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    } else if (selected.equals("To-Do-Liste")) {
                        Snackbar.make(view, "spinner: to-do-liste", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }

                }

                override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {
                    Log.i("Placeholder", "XXXXXXXXXXX")
                }

            }
        }
    }

    fun createRecyclerView(context: Context) {

        var adapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder>? = null
        val layoutManager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        val recyclerView: RecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = layoutManager
        recyclerView.adapter = CustomAdapter(context)

    }

}
```

#### CustomAdapter.kt (== RecyclerViewAdapter)

```
package com.example.todo

import DatabaseHandler
import ParentId
import android.content.Context
import android.database.Cursor
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
//https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview

class CustomAdapter(private val context: Context)
    : RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    var data = getDataForRecyclerView()
    val entries: Array<String> = data[0] as Array<String>
    val types: Array<Int> = data[1] as Array<Int>

    class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view){
        val entity: TextView
        val entity_container: CardView
        val entity_constraint_layout: ConstraintLayout
        val entity_icon: ImageView

        init {
            entity = view.findViewById(R.id.entity)
            entity_container = view.findViewById(R.id.entity_container)
            entity_constraint_layout = view.findViewById(R.id.entity_constraint_layout)
            entity_icon = view.findViewById(R.id.entity_icon)

        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CustomAdapter.ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.layout_recycler_layer_tdl,
                parent,
                false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CustomAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        //Der TextView einen String aus dem Datensatz zuweisen.
        holder.entity.text = entries[position]
        //identifizieren, ob es sich um eine Ebene oder eine TDL handelt
        val type = types[position]
        if (type==0){
            holder.entity_icon.apply {
                setImageResource(R.drawable.layer_icon)
                contentDescription = "Ebene"
            }
        } else if (type==1){
            holder.entity_icon.apply {
                setImageResource(R.drawable.tdl_icon)
                contentDescription = "To-Do-Liste"
            }
        }
        //Wenn die jeweilige Cardview gedrückt wird.
        holder.entity_container.setOnClickListener{

            when {
                //geklicktes Objekt ist eine Ebene
                types[position] == 0 -> {
                    val db = DatabaseHandler(context).readableDatabase
                    val query: String = "Select id from layer where name='${holder.entity.text.toString()}'"
                    val result = db.rawQuery(query, null)
                    if (result.count > 0){
                        result.moveToFirst()
                        ParentId.parentId = result.getInt(0)
                        Log.i("oBVH", "Ebene")
                        //TODO: Refresh MainActivity

                    }
                    result.close()

                }
                //geklicktes Objekt ist eine To-Do-List
                types[position] == 1 -> {
                    Log.i("oBVH", "tdl")
                }
                else -> {
                    Log.i("oBVH", "Fehler")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = entries.size

    fun getDataForRecyclerView(): Array<Any> {
        val parentId = ParentId.parentId
        val db = DatabaseHandler(context).readableDatabase
        val queryLayer = "select name from layer where parent_id=$parentId"
        val queryTdl = "select name from tdl where layer_id=$parentId"
        val layerResult: Cursor? = db.rawQuery(queryLayer, null)
        val tdlResult: Cursor? = db.rawQuery(queryTdl, null)

        //Iterator
        var i = 0
        //Länge des Ziel-Arrays
        val length: Int = layerResult?.count!! + tdlResult?.count!!
        //String-Array mit Anzahl Elemente == Länge des Cursors, damit mittels set Daten übergeben werden können.
        val dataset = Array<String>(length){""}
        //Int-Array um später festzustellen, ob ein Entry im CardView eine Ebene oder eine TDL ist
        val type = Array<Int>(length){0}
        //Betroffene Layer extrahieren und dem dataset String-Array hinzufügen
        if (layerResult.count > 0) {
            layerResult.moveToFirst()
            do {
                val data: String = layerResult.getString(layerResult.getColumnIndex("name"))
                dataset.set(i, data)
                i+=1
            } while (layerResult.moveToNext())

        }
        layerResult.close()

        //Betroffene To-Do-Listen extrahieren und dem dataset String-Array hinzufügen
        val tdlDataset = Array<String>(tdlResult.count){""}
        if (tdlResult.count > 0) {
            tdlResult.moveToFirst()
            do {
                val data: String = tdlResult.getString(tdlResult.getColumnIndex("name"))
                dataset.set(i, data)
                type.set(i, 1)
                i+=1
            } while (tdlResult.moveToNext())
        }
        tdlResult.close()

        return arrayOf(dataset, type)
    }

}
```

#### ParentId.kt (used to change/retrieve the layer/folder)

```
class ParentId {
    companion object {
        var parentId: Int = 0
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you want your activity reloaded to get the data ?

Answer (score 0):

There is an answer to your question, but it's better if you do other stuff instead:

First of: If only the RecyclerView data changes, you can call notifyDataSetChanged on the adapter after you update the internal data. While doing that you can of course also update other stuff that's shown in the activity if that isn't the only thing.

If you want (an ugly) easy solution, perhaps you can start another activity and pass a hint to what data should be shown in the intent, so e.g. pass a foldername and the next activity knows what to show.

Edit: Just saw your ParentId class, you normally don't use static objects in Android like that. Consider changing that to Intent extras in the future but you might not see bugs due to that for now.

Another solution would be using fragments and exchanging the current one with the new one, that's pretty similar to the second solution but better.

At the end, the first option is the best. Find out a way to only update the data and recyclerview, that also allows stuff like animations and might lead to less errors. If you need to handle back presses you can do that with onBackPressed()

Also, only calling the Recyclerview setup method (instead of restarting anything) might already help, I'd still change that afterwards though